# Inserting variable from input in form action

Tags: php, forms

I have a form which queries the user about which type of list he wants to see. As the submit button is pressed, I want to be able to have the value listtype displayed in the address so I can access it by using GET methods, for instance to change the page of the list that is being shown. In this form, I tried the following code:

```
<?php
    echo '<form method=post action="index.php?operacao=checkList&number=1&pagesize=10&listtype=', $_GET['listtype'] ,'" name="listForm">
    <ol>

        <li><label for="listtype">Type:</label>
        <select name="listtype">
        <option value="default">Select</option>
        <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
        <option value="nurse">Nurse</option>
        <option value="patient">Patient</option>
        </select></li>

        <div id="form-button">
            <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javapopup();"></li>
        </div>

    </ol>
    </form>';
?>
```

Although, as I open the form, I get an error that says the variable `listtype` is not defined. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have `<form method=post` and you're asking for a GET. Try using `<form method="get"`

Comment: Your undefined error message could be caused by an unnamed variable. For instance: `$var=$_GET['var'];` we need to see your PHP handler.

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET['listtype']` is not going to be set the first time you load this page which is why you are getting this error. You need to check to see if it is set before you use it and, if it is not, not use it in that situation. In your case because your form is set to POST it will never populate the `$_GET` superglobal which will cause this error to never go away.

```
echo '<form method=post action="index.php?operacao=checkList&number=1&pagesize=10&listtype=', $_GET['listtype'] ,'" name="listForm">
```

probably should resemble something like this:

```
$listype = (isset($_POST['listtype'])) ? $_POST['listtype'] : '';
echo '<form method=post action="index.php?operacao=checkList&number=1&pagesize=10&listtype=', $listype ,'" name="listForm">
```

FYI, using a raw `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable in your code the way you are using it leaves you wide open to Cross Site Scripting attacks. So you should be sanitizing this variable anyway.

```
$listype = (isset($_POST['listtype'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['listtype']) : '';
echo '<form method=post action="index.php?operacao=checkList&number=1&pagesize=10&listtype=', $listype ,'" name="listForm">
```

Comment: So using `post` as the form method doesn't matter?

Comment: Actually, that's another issue they have. Let me address that.

Comment: I knew there was something more to just the form method, which is why I didn't want to make it as an actual answer. Questions like these it seems, always opens up a can of worms, as it were.

Comment: Agreed. Once I see more than two issues in one code snippet I just vote to close as not knowing enough about what they're doing just yet.

Comment: Exactly. The OP has some JS happening `javapopup()` and probably querying a DB. Next thing we know, risks in coming back to say "It still doesn't work... my info doesn't show up now etc." Yep, see it all too often, and a vote to close is usually what's best to do until we know everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I tried the last piece of code you suggested and although I get the correct value of listtype when I do `echo $_POST['listtype'];` in the list page, I still get an empty string next to listtype= in the address, which isn't making much sense. I also removed the javascript I had on the onclick which I think was avoiding the binary operator to be evaluated.